# Does talking about jury nullification get you blocked from jury duty?

Tags: united-states, jury, jury-nullification

I've heard from a few different (non-authoritative) sources that talking about jury nullification will get you removed from a jury. Is that actually true? If so, does it therefore follow that if you get a jury summons you don't want to do, you can get out of it just by loudly talking about jury nullification?

Comment: And https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27098/what-tactics-can-a-juror-use-to-get-excused-from-jury-duty

Comment: If you do not want to do it for a particular reason such as a hard deadline event, more than likely you could get off for just that reason.  Personally I had a jury summons that was to occur the day before my finals in Uni started.  Although my half of the pool was dismissed the night before, a family member with court room experience in the jurisdiction explained that mentioning something of that nature would be the quickest way to get dismissed for cause (I'm clearly going to be biased to what ever outcome gets me out of duty fastest, not the actual just finding.).